# Handschlitten vs. Schlitten

Tags: synonym, semantics

In what exactly differs a *Handschlitten* from a *Schlitten*?

Aren't they both sledges?

Is a *Handschlitten* hand-drawn, while a *Schlitten* isn't?

(This is about the only sensible answer I've been able to come up with myself in trying to explain the difference, if any, between these two words).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course any [Schlitten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlitten) is a sledge but they differ in construction or usage. This is reflected in German composite nouns:

> *Hundeschlitten, Pferdeschlitten, Holzschlitten, Rodelschlitten, Sportschlitten, ...*

From these a ***Hand**schlitten* is a manually drawn sledge.

By this it differs from other vehicles, and we even have own traffic rules for them:

> §73 StVO: [...] Bei Handwagen, Handkarren und **Handschlitten** genügt jedoch eine Lampe, die nach vorne weiß und nach hinten rot leuchtet [...]

[image]

<sup>[Historical view of a Lumberjack drawing a *Handschlitten*](http://www.ckrumlov.info/img.php?img=2659&LANG=de)</sup>

Comment: @user26328: see image for illustration :)

Comment: Wow! Do they still exist?

Comment: I doubt it (but I'm not in th lumberjack business). See https://www.salzburgerland.com/de/magazin/ziachschlittenfahren-in-maria-alm/ for an Austrian event.